# Find path length from ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to integrate a system of differential equations. Let $p(t)$ be a path in the unit disk in the complex plane with $p(0)=0$. Write $p(t)=r\exp(i\theta)$ for some $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$ and $r\geq0$. Suppose

$$\frac{d}{dt}p(t)=\exp(i[\theta+\phi(r)])$$

where $r=|p(t)|$ and $\phi(r)=\phi_0(1-r)$ for some constant $\phi_0$. Also define $\frac{d}{dt}p(0)=1$. In other words, $p(t)$ is always rotating according to its distance from the origin. I have two questions:

1. Is there an explicit formula for $p(t)$?
2. What is path length of $p(t)$ from $t=1$ to $T$?

Below is a plot of the vector field and $p(t)$ for $\phi_0=-1.197$.

[image]

Comment: You just wrote $p(t) = r exp(i\theta)$, where is it a function of $t$?

Comment: I've edited my post, but $r$ denotes the magnitude of $p(t)$ so it is a function of $t$.

Comment: What is $\theta(p)$ in your plot?

Comment: At some point $p$, say with $\arg=\theta$, the direction fields points towards $\theta+\phi(r)$

Comment: The velocity on the path is $|\dot{p}| = 1$, so the path length is very easy to compute if you already know the time it takes to travel along it (here $T-1$).

Comment: Yes, in fact I am most interested in finding such a $T$.

Comment: Are you looking for the time $T$ at which the path reaches the boundary of the disk?

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{d}{dt}p(t)=\exp(i[\theta+\phi(r) ])=\cos(\theta+\phi(r))+i\sin(\theta+\phi(r))$$
$$p=r\cos(\theta)+ir\sin(\theta)$$
$$\frac{d}{dt}(r\cos(\theta))+i\frac{d}{dt}(r\sin(\theta))=\cos(\theta+\phi(r))+i\sin(\theta+\phi(r))$$
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{d}{dt}(r\cos(\theta))=\frac{dr}{dt}\cos(\theta)-r\sin(\theta)\frac{d\theta}{dt}=\cos(\theta+\phi(r))\\
\frac{d}{dt}(r\sin(\theta))=\frac{dr}{dt}\sin(\theta)+r\cos(\theta)\frac{d\theta}{dt}=\sin(\theta+\phi(r))
\end{cases}$$

$$\begin{cases}
\cos(\theta)dr-r\sin(\theta)d\theta=\cos(\theta+\phi(r))dt\\
\sin(\theta)dr+r\cos(\theta)d\theta=\sin(\theta+\phi(r))dt
\end{cases}$$
$$\frac{\sin(\theta)\frac{dr}{d\theta}+r\cos(\theta)}{\cos(\theta)\frac{dr}{d\theta}-r\sin(\theta)}=\frac{\sin(\theta+\phi(r))}{\cos(\theta+\phi(r)) }$$
$$\left(-\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta+\phi(r))+\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta+\phi(r))\right)\frac{dr}{d\theta}=r\left(\cos(\theta)\cos(\theta+\phi(r))+\sin(\theta)\sin(\theta+\phi(r))\right)$$
$$\sin(\phi(r))\frac{dr}{d\theta}=r\cos(\phi(r))$$
$$\theta=\int \frac{1}{r}\tan(\phi(r))dr$$
With $\phi(r)=\phi_0(1-r)$ :
$$\theta(r)=\int \frac{1}{r}\tan(\phi_0(1-r))dr$$
This is the equation of the trajectory (in polar coordinates) expressed on the form of a function defined by an integral.

Theoretically in is possible to express $\theta(r)$ on closed form. But this is complicated and the closed form includes a special function (Polylogarithm).

Practically one have to use numerical calculus to continue. A-fortiori for the inverse function $r(\theta)$.

Answer (score 0):

Using the chain rule, we have $ p'(t) = (r'(t) + ir(t)\theta'(t))e^{i\theta(t)} $, so the equation becomes

$$ r'(t) + ir(t)\theta'(t) = e^{i\phi_0(1-r)} $$

where $r(0)=r_0$ and $\theta(0)=\theta_0$. Matching real and imaginary parts, we get

\begin{align}
r' &= \cos(\phi_0(1-r)) \\
\theta' &= \frac{1}{r}\sin(\phi_0(1-r)) 
\end{align}

Then $r(t)$ is given (implicitly) by

$$ t = \int_{r_0}^r \frac{1}{\cos(\phi_0(1-u))}du $$

Since $r'(0)=\operatorname{Re}(p'(0)) = 1$, $r_0$ is given by solving $1 = \frac{1}{\cos(\phi_0(1-r_0))}$

As for the path length, perform the integration

$$ \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \left\vert p'(t) \right\vert dt = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} 1\ dt = t_2 - t_1 $$

Since $p'(t)$ has constant magnitude.